# How to read TXT file and use the lines as float values?

Tags: python, split, txt

```
0, 0
0.4859, 2.5468
0.9718, 5.0936
1.4577, 7.6404
1.9436, 10.1872
2.4295, 12.734
2.9154, 15.2808
3.4013, 17.8276
```

I have a text file that looks like the above structure. I am trying to take the 1st float in each line as x_location value, and the second as a y_location value and put them on a list. I tried everything I could from data.split to item[0] reads. But cant figure out a way to do it. In the end I would like it to look like:

```
x_location = [0, 0.4859, 0.9718, 1.4577, 1.9436]
y_location = [0, 2.5468, 5.0936, 7.6404, 10.1872]
```

Any way I can achieve this?

I tried to use data.split but kept getting str values which I couldnt reliably turn it into float values. With item[0] I couldnt find a way to turn the str into 2 different items.

Comment: Hi! One of the most important tags to include is what programming language you're working in, so that the right people find your question to help you. Please click [edit] and add that, as well as some actual examples of code you've tried, so people can see what you already know, and where you're going wrong - see the page in the [help] with tips on writing a [mre].

Comment: You will need to find a way to "parse" those strings into floats

Comment: OT instead of parallel arrays of X and Y values, can you store each line in some "point" structure? You will stll need to parse both values separately and then combine into a point

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
x_location = []
y_location = []
with open('yourtxtfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        x, y = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')]
        x_location.append(x)
        y_location.append(y)

print(x_location)
print(y_location)
```